# Could someone explain me what is a Clopen Set

Tags: general-topology

I came across this term while studying for a test and got curious as to what this actually is.

could someone please the concept in a relatively easy language?

Comment: A set that is both **clo**sed and **open**.

Comment: "Sets are not doors" :)

Comment: but what does that mean exactly, how is something part of 2 in a plane defined by binary? how can something be a 1 and a 0

Comment: But it's not binary. A set is not *either open or closed*. It can be neither. And it can be both. Th emost trivial example: in any topological space, the whole space is both open and closed.

Comment: The definitions of open and closed sets are not mutually exclusive. A set is defined to be closed if its complement is not open.

Comment: @player3236 Ahem. *is*

Comment: what will the set be like, what different is it from a set for example [1,4) and where is it used?

Comment: In $\mathbb R$, $[1,4)$ is neither open or closed.

Comment: @Col_Balt First of all, there can't be any clopen set (apart from the whole space and the empty set) in a topological space that is [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). Because the clopen set S, which is open, has a complement which is also open (because S is closed), hence the space is not connected.

Comment: You are not the first one to be confused by this concept. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Comment: It is an unfortunate fact that in the spaces one first learns about, $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^n, [0,1]$, the notion of clopen is trivial, because the only clopen sets are $\emptyset$ and the space itself. This might deceive one into thinking that the notion of being clopen is just a quirk in the definitions, but that's not the case. If you move to other spaces, you'll find that clopen sets can have a very rich structure.

Answer (score 3):

As in the comments, clopen means both open and closed.

As an example, take a disconnected space $X$ like the union of two disjoint intervals, with the subspace topology, in $\Bbb R$.  Then each interval would be clopen in $X$.

Clopenness is a topological notion. Remember, open sets are designated subsets of the space.  Closed sets are then sets whose complements are open.  Note that the two notions are not exclusive of each other.

Answer (score 0):

A "clopen" set meets both the definition of a closed set and an open set.

The classic examples are the real numbers and the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you my understanding within the narrow focus of considering all elements in the complex plane (i.e. $\mathbb{C}$).

This understanding is based exclusively on chapter 2 (*The Rudiments of Plane Topology*) from "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory" : 1992 : Bruce Palka.

$\mathbb{C}$ consists of all #'s of the form $a + ib$, 
where $a$ and $b$ are real #'s and $i$ represents $\sqrt{-1}.$

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is deemed open, if and only if 
every element in $S$ is an *interior* point of $S$.

An element $s \in S$ is deemed an interior point, if and only if 
there exists some $\delta > 0$, such that 
for all $z \in \mathbb{C},$ where $0 \leq |z - s| < \delta,$
$z \in S.$

Here, given two complex #'s $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv,$ 
then |z - w| is defined to be $\sqrt{(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2}.$

Given any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$, its complement is defined to be 
the set of all elements that are in $\mathbb{C}$ but are not in $S.$

A subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is deemed *closed* if and only if 
its complement is deemed open.

Here, it is immediate that $\mathbb{C}$ and its complement $\phi$ (i.e. the empty set) are both open.  
Consequently, both of these sets are also closed.

What remains is to prove that no other subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ can be simultaneously open and closed.  To do this, I must introduce the notion of a boundary point of a set.

Given a subset $S$, a point $b$ (which may or may not be an element in $S$) is deemed a boundary point of $S$ if and only if 
For any positive $\delta$, no matter how small, the set 
{$z ~: ~0 \leq |z - b| < \delta$} will contain 
at least one element that is in $S,$
and at least one element that is not in $S.$

Two of the results from chapter 2 (*The Rudiments of Plane Topology*) are

(1) 
If a set is closed then it **must** contain **all** of its boundary points.

(2) 
If a set is open then it **can not** contain **any** of its boundary points.

Based on these two results, the only way a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ can simultaneously be open and closed is if the subset **contains no boundary points**.

**Conjecture**
To the best of my knowledge, the only such subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are the set $\mathbb{C}$ itself and its complement $\phi$.

The following analysis represents a somewhat informal proof of the conjecture.

Let $S$ represent a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $T$ represent the complement of $S.$  This means that neither $S$ nor $T$ are empty sets.

Let $s$ be any element in $S$, and let $t$ be any element in $T.$ 
Let $L$ denote all elements on the **line segment** that connect $s$ and $t$.

That is, $L ~\equiv~$
{$ z ~: ~z = s + [a\times (t-s)] ~: ~a \in \mathbb{R}, ~0 \leq a \leq 1$}.

Clearly, when examining the elements of $L$ of the form $s + [a\times (t-s)],$ 
when $a = 0$, the element equals $s$, which is in $S,$
and when $a = 1$, the element equals $t$, which is in $T.$

Consider the set $B$ of all of the scalars $b$ such that 
$0 \leq b \leq 1$ and
all elements in $L$ of the form $s + [b\times (t-s)],$ are in $S$.

Let $c$ denote the smallest element in $B$ 
such that for any $\delta > 0$, 
the interval $(c - \delta, c]$ contains 
at least one element that is in $B$ and 
the interval $[c, c+\delta)$ contains 
at least one element that is not in $B.$

Then the element in $L$ represented by $[s + c\times (t-s)],$ **must be**
a boundary point of $S.$

The above analysis hinges on proving that regardless of the nature of the underlying set $S$, a subset of $\mathbb{C},$ the scalar $c$ must exist.
My knowledge of topology is **way too unsophisticated** to discuss proving the existence of the scalar $c.$

A minor variation of the above analyis is that since $\mathbb{R}$ is deemed a *complete ordered field,* and since $B$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, there is a real # $d$ that is the least upper bound for $B.$
Under this presumption, then $[s + d\times (t-s)]$ is (also) a boundary point for $S.$

Again, I lack the knowledge or sophistication to discuss the above presumption.